# Any way to generate c stubs with javah?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Is there an easy way to generate stubs for prototypes generated with javah?  The actual stubs option has never actually done anything for newer java versions.

Yeah sure, I can generate the header files with the function signatures, but then I have to go and put parameter names on each of those when I do the C implementation.  I'd like the parameters to just automatically match the names I used in the original .java file.

Any way to do this?